# AlarmManager android can't scheduling with cycle is smaller 1000 miliseconds

Tags: android, alarmmanager, scheduling

I'm developing a scheduling by AlarmManager with cycle is 500ms
However When run cycle is 1000 ms

This is my code:

```
public class SchedulerAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive enter");
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Layer2_SchedulerAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
       //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1 * 2 * 1, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
        am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() + 500, pi);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
          Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm enter");
          AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          Intent i = new Intent(context, Layer2_SchedulerAlarm.class);
          PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
          am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 500, pi);
    }

}


public class Myervice extends Service {
     SchedulerAlarm SchedulerAlarm scheduler = new Layer2_SchedulerAlarm();

     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           LibJNIWrapper.selectGW(0);
          Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand enter");
          scheduler.setAlarm(this);
          return START_NOT_STICKY;
      }
}

Manifest:
   <receiver android:name=".Layer2_SchedulerAlarm"></receiver>
```

this is result when run, cycle enter onReceive about 1000ms (don't my expectation is 500ms)

```
11-29 13:26:56.921 4938-4938/com.joydus.aimon D/TEST: onReceive enter
11-29 13:26:57.954 4938-4938/com.joydus.aimon D/TEST: onReceive enter
11-29 13:26:58.994 4938-4938/com.joydus.aimon D/TEST: onReceive enter
11-29 13:27:00.049 4938-4938/com.joydus.aimon D/TEST: onReceive enter
11-29 13:27:01.080 4938-4938/com.joydus.aimon D/TEST: onReceive enter
11-29 13:27:02.099 4938-4938/com.joydus.aimon D/TEST: onReceive enter
```

Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Don't use `AlarmManager` for intervals that small.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, your use case. But if you app is doing something in background, and only when the app is open, and not closed. Use [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

I use it for 20 ms, as required by the library I am using.